# Adding an image blob column to oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to add a new column for storing an image to the my current db/table.

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD LOGO mediumblob NOT NULL;
```

However, I am getting an error that i am unsure how to fix.

Here's the error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - `ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD LOGO
>   mediumblob NOT NULL` Error report - ORA-00604: error occurred at
>   recursive SQL level 1 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
>   ORA-06512: at line 47 ORA-00902: invalid datatype

For oracle do I need some other data type other than blob or medium blob?
I ran across `ORDSYS.ORDIMGB` but I am not sure if that's what I need to use instead of medium blob.

**EDIT:** I have tried using just blob but I get this error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: "mediumblob" is not a datatype. Try "blob" instead.

Comment: i tried blob previously. It gives me this error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: You're getting that error from running `alter table account add logo blob not null`? Because that works fine for me. Or do you get it when trying to insert to the table?

Comment: Could there be a DDL trigger that's firing when you `alter`, and which is throwing that error?

Comment: its working when i take out not null

Comment: OK, but it seems to be something specific to your DB, like a DDL trigger, which we can't see. I'd guess there's a  trigger examining or logging the action, and it's badly written. When you do it with BLOB and not null, are there additional messages - you've only shown the ORA-06502 for that scenario, but if there's a stack of messages can you include the whole statement and error stack, as you did for the `mediumblob` attempt?